# browser cache not working properly in spring project

Tags: java, jsp, caching

In my project I don't clear the browser cache, but when user clicks the back button it doesn't load the page from browser cache. Instead it usually reloads the page, but sometimes the browser uses the cache to load the page.

How can I force the page to always load from the browser cache when the user hits back button?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Cache-Control headers as required.

You can check the details about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#cache-control)

Comment: It is sent via response headers .. i think so it will be in your java filter

Comment: i added response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "required"); in filter but still same problem occurs

Comment: I think so you should set the max-age too